# Visual Studio 2008 freeze after save

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I recently added about a dozen classes from another solution into my current solution in Visual Studio.  After adding these classes, Visual Studio started freezing for about 10 seconds whenever I Save.  The cursor disappears and mouse clicks and keys do nothing.

Some interesting points:

- Even after I removed the classes, the freezing behavior is still there.
- Freezing occurs whether I've made changes to the code or not.
- This behavior ONLY seems to affect this particular version of this solution.  No other solutions exhibit this behavior.  Older versions of this solution are not affected.
- In Sysinternals Process Explorer, whenever I save in Visual Studio, the I/O bytes graph jumps from 0 to 2MB for about 5 seconds, then drops to about 1 MB for a split second, then jumps back to 2MB for another 5 seconds.  Processor use goes up to about 3-5% during this time.

Here are the details of my setup:

C# Silverlight project (maybe 20 classes), .NET version 3.5 SP1, Visual Studio 2008 v9.0.30729 SP1.

**EDIT:**

I edited this question extensively to reflect the more detailed information.  I thought this might be preferable to starting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure if it's the same issue, but I've experienced similar slowdowns because of the Windows Forms Designer.  I fixed this by going to

Tools --> Options --> Windows Forms Designer

and turning AutoToolboxPopulate to off.  It's a longshot, but you might as well give it a try.  Also, one thing I do for larger solutions is compile from the command line instead of in visual studio.  You just need to open a Visual Studio Command Prompt and use msbuild (solution name | project name).  You can also use /m for multicore compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, this did the trick:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946344 titled 'You may experience performance issues in the IDE after you use Visual Studio 2008 to build a Visual Basic project'

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, I'm using C#, and the hotfix is specifically for VB.  Also, I'm not using lots of XML comments, and the slowdown happens right AFTER compilation.  Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just finished an all day chase down of this bug.  In my experience I found it to be dependent on line count.  This value was machine specific however.  On my machine it was a line count limit of 35,129 and was not size specific.  A coworker did not have the same issues when saving the same file however I was able to recreate the problem inserting blank lines.  I then retracted to one line less then the threshold and added characters to increase the file size which did not create a problem so I can say with certainty that for me it was about line count.  An indicator also might be a small bent blue arrow next to the line count in VS.  When I would exceed the line count this indicator appeared on line 35,129.

Edit: If this is your problem(and represents a very large class) then a suitable fix can be implemented through partial classes.  For more info check out http://www.techrepublic.com/article/splitting-a-class-across-files-in-vbnet/6179621